# How translate object accurately with different kind of value on the screen? Searching for truth

Tags: android, coordinates

Hi I have a problem with controlling position of my object on the screen. When I create activity every object on the screen is placed with animation and troubles starting here. Firstly I tried to placed all things with pixel coordinates, which based on height and width of screen. I want to take it from device when activity starts. During the coding I think the better way will be use the % values cause I don't need to think about diferent screen resolution and stuff like this.

The picture shows, how I thought the screen looks with different values,but I'm wrong.I make the assumption, that the layout match to the parent, so it have nearly this same size as the screen
 [image]

Cause the range of values for % and %p is from -100 to 100, so where is -100%, when I put something like -60%p I can't see it on the screen. I try to play with the object by changing the values and see results, but for example 
object represented by

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:duration="3000"
android:startOffset="7000">
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="2600"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:fromYDelta="-10"
    android:toYDelta="-10%p"
    />
<rotate 
    android:fromDegrees="359"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    />
```

is higher on the screen then object represented by:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true"
android:duration="3000"
android:startOffset="12000">
<rotate 
    android:fromDegrees="359"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    />
<translate 
    android:fromXDelta="-599"
    android:toXDelta="40%p"
    android:fromYDelta="-499"
    android:toYDelta="-10%p"
    />
```

I think they should be on this same vertical level, because `android:toYDelta` is the same.

When we are putting the values to xml code, we are placing the right top corner of the object in my opinion.

Please clear the way I think about coordinates of different type, and where are mistakes?

I would be grateful for every answer.

Comment: Show the layout. It defines how the Android works with coordinates on the screen. Now you are showing us the animation, but not how it is placed.

Comment: I try to update this question by the end of this week